# Unity project, Visual Studio 2019 included file disappears when reopen

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I have an unity project with structure like this:

```
Scripts
 |--csFile1.cs
 |
Resources
 |--XML
 |   |----xmlFile1.xml
 |
 |--JSON
 |   |----jsonFile1.json
```

The `jsonFile1.json` is not included in the vs solution. What I did is in the Solution Explorer click on <kbd>Show All Files</kbd>, then on the `JSON` folder or on the json file name right click then choose <kbd>Include In Porject</kbd>, then the json files are included properly.

However every time I reopen the vs project, the json files are not in the solution.

The `XML` files are included properly but I don't remember how I managed to do it.

Anyone knows how to properly include a file into the solution in a Unity project? Thanks!

Comment: did you read [The Resources folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html)? Why do you hace `.cs` files in your Resources folder?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for your help with the format. That was a mistake, the Scripts folder is the same level with Resources folder. I've corrected the structure.

Answer (score 0):

====Updates====

Sorry, it seems the following way is still not the solution. After restarting my Visual Studio, the json files are excluded again.

====Original Answer====

After almost 3 years, I accidentally bumped into the solution: In the File menu, just choose "move 'file name' to xx Assembly". Usually you want to move it into the "Assembly-CSharp" in my case.